# Преобразование промежутков времени в JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется база данных, в которой хранится дата и промежуток времени в тиках (.NET). Данные из базы сериализуются и передаются в JSON-объекте. Как перевести полученные данные в корректный формат и отобразить в html-разметке? Как затем правильно выполнить обратное преобразование для записи в базу? 
На страницу необходимо вывести дату из базы, количество дней (полученное из тиков), а так же дату, равную сумме исходной даты и количества дней.

**UPDATE**

JSON:

```
{
"BeginDateTime":"2015-02-22T00:00:00",
"Ticks":77760000000000
}
```

Значения в SQL:

```
BeginDateTime: 22.02.2015 
Ticks: 77760000000000
```

На выходе нужно:

```
Start 22.02.2015 - datepicker
Span 90 суток - text input
End 23.05.2015 - datepicker
```

Comment: приведите пример значений, и соответствующий им выход

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В решении задачи поможет плагин [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).
Пример кода с вашими данными:

```
var start_date = "2015-02-22T00:00:00"; // исходная дата
var ticks = 77760000000000/10000; // переводим тики в миллисекунды
var format = 'DD.MM.YYYY'; // задаем формат даты
var start = moment(start_date);
var end = moment(start_date).add(ticks, 'ms');

console.log("Start: " + start.format(format)); //Start: 22.02.2015
console.log("Period: " + moment.duration(ticks).asDays()); // Period: 90
console.log("End: " + end.format(format)); // End: 23.05.2015
```